# Error while executing the fortran code through gfortran

Tags: linux, gcc, fortran, gfortran

i want to execute two fortran file `x.f` and `y.f` attached in the link

for this i did

`gfortran -o x x.f`

`gfortran -o y y.f`

However in both the cases i am getting error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Additionally, i searched over the internet for its solution, but i am not getting proper answer.I hope experts may help me executing these fortran codes.

Comment: The compiler seems to be telling you that neither source file represents a complete program, nor do the two together do so.

Comment: I have not reviewed the sources, and I will not review them from an external site.  If you want us to evaluate code, then edit the question to include a [mre], directly in the question.  Otherwise, there's not much else we can say.

Comment: You should not paste the full code.  Read the description of a MRE to which I already linked.  Choose one of the files, and prepare an MRE from it.  This will require some work on your part.

Comment: But my best guess without seeing any code is that the sources you are looking at provide only functions and subroutines, possibly in modules, and not any main program.

Comment: The real file name of "x.f, y.f" is `gnssSNR.f` as line one says. Full context https://github.com/kristinemlarson/gnssSNR → `$ make` : No errors.

Comment: Yes. You cannot plug out a file connected to ~11 other files. Must be compiled with the makefile. `cd gnssSNR/ && make`  ( After getting the package with : `git clone https://github.com/kristinemlarson/gnssSNR.git` )

Comment: Well, change to a new folder, and clone the files again with git. ......... You cannot say "no makefile", when it is visible and can be read / downloaded https://github.com/kristinemlarson/gnssSNR

Comment: I read the file name as `gnssSNR.f` : https://github.com/kristinemlarson/gnssSNR